# Cannot load ipynb file into jupyter running in docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, containers, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am using Windows Docker Desktop to run Jupyter container. Image I am using is minimal notebook.

Below is how I run. Click Images -> Run and set options. (port number is set to 0)

[image]

Left side is my host's file explorer, there is ruconsumption.ipynb under `C:\Users\myname\docker` folder. This is mounted as volume of this container and is under container path `/app`

I can now go to my Container -> Terminal and see this volume

```
$ whoami
jovyan
$ pwd
/app
$ ls -la
total 2844
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root    4096 May 23 00:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 May 23 00:25 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2907883 May 23 00:09 ruconsumption.ipynb
```

So host -> container volume linking seems to work.

But when I try to open this file inside container Jupyter by click File -> Open from path, I get this error

[image]

I am stuck in here. I am suspecting it could be permission issue, or maybe this is not correct way of loading ipynb file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I thought it was permission issue but search tells me that Docker Desktop always runs as root. But then who is `jovyan` ?

Comment: Instead of Open from path, I just clicked "Upload Files" button, and I was actually just able to navigate to my host directory.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from misunderstanding of "Volumes".. So Volumes you would only need for application data / server side data that is needed for container to run?? If I am accessing this container using browser, am I "client" of that application

Comment: First time using any container so please bear with my lack of understanding.

Comment: `jovyan` is the user running Jupyter inside your container's virtual machine, I suspect. What happens when you run `pwd` inside a new Jupyter notebook you initiate opening? Is it the same as the terminal says? About "So Volumes you would only need for application data / server side data..." question, I would expect that to be a way to provide the notebook and the data, too. It's odd that it isn't working. Using 'Upload Files' to get it there has me concerned. Make sure you then right-click in the file navigation pane & 'download' back to a completely separate directory the modified notebook.

Comment: <continued> I worry that 'uploaded' notebok is in temporary space of the running container and if you shut the container down it would be gone. So just be cautious.  .... I should have also added when discussing volumes above ... Also volumes are great for insuring the output & results of your scripts or notebooks execution remains persistent on your system when the container is no longer running.